# npm uninstall -g create-react-app and yarn global remove create-react-app not working

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to uninstall **create-react-app** globally using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and `yarn global remove create-react-app`.
I uninstalled node and installed it still same problem.

[image]

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` :

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm cache verify`
3. `npx clear-npx-cache` to clear your npx cache.
4. `npx create-react-app your-app` or `npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx clear-npx-cache
npx create-react-app <app_name>
```

The above command does

1. uninstall create-react-app CLI globally.
2. npx clear cache.
3. create a react application